# Python 2 and CSV writerows() encoding

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I need to export data (from layer attributes) to new csv file. I use Python 2.x (Qgis ESSEN 2.14) and native CSV python module.

Here is my error :

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv, os

obj = [[1, u'OPP_1-8_LT_26301_WDHB_001', u"CD26_Donat-on", u'BASE', u"test-d1547", u'refdv', u'to create', u'1x144FO + 1x2FO', u'1 C > 144', u'2018', u'Unknow', u'C d\xe9partement', 3, 279, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, u'Trait\xe9e']]
docName = "C:/someFolder/new_file.csv"

with open(docName, "w") as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out,delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(obj)
    out.close()
```

In python 3.x no problem, there is no issue because of **`encode`** option but i can't wait new LTR Qgis 3 (python 3) :

```
with open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write('\ufeff')
```

Many solutions exists to fix this encoding issue in Python 2.x. But i need a feedback. 
Actualy, i thing to use [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) module.

What is the best solution in python 2 / pyqgis ?

Comment: Thanks to close my usefull "off-topic" !!  I had find my solution and reuse pyqgis (is Pyqgis not GIS ? ^^ ) to solved this problem.